# Why does this query in this n-n relation return nothing?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sequelize.js

I'm trying to do the following query but nothing happends. I get no results.

```
SELECT * FROM "product" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    "product_filter" 
    INNER JOIN "filter_value" 
    ON "filter_value"."filterValueId" = "product_filter"."filterValueId") 
ON "product"."productId" = "product_filter"."productId" 
WHERE "product"."isAdult" = false 
AND ("filter_value"."filterValueId" = '4' 
AND "filter_value"."filterValueId" = '8');
```

I know that the problem comes from the `filterValueId` that has to be equal to 4 and 8. If I remove one of them, I get the result. But I need the result of both.
`filter_value` is a relationnal table for a n-n relation.

The query looks correct to me but nothing come out.
What is worse is that **when I execute the LEFT OUTER JOIN query, I get results**:

```
"product_filter" 
INNER JOIN "filter_value" 
ON "filter_value"."filterValueId" = "product_filter"."filterValueId"
```

I use sequelize to built the following relation:

```
db.product.belongsToMany(
db.filterValue, 
{ 
    through: db.productFilter, 
    as: 'productFilters', 
    foreignKey: 'productId' 
});
db.filterValue.belongsToMany(
db.product, 
{ 
    through: db.productFilter, 
    as: 'productFilters', 
    foreignKey: 'filterValueId' 
});
```

I've check tables content multiple times and everything is correct.
I really don't understand **why this query returns nothing?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to understand why it returns nothing.  The filter value cannot be both 4 and 8 at the same time.

I think you want something like this:

```
select p.*
from "product" p
where p.ProductId in (select pf.ProductId
                      from product_filter pf 
                      where pf.filterValueId in (4, 8)
                      group by pf.ProductId
                      having count(distinct pf.filterValueId = 2)
                     );
```

Note:  You do not need the filter table at all, because the filter value is in `product_filter`.  (This assumes it is not needed for some type of filtering.)

You might find the use of two `exists` subqueries faster:

```
select p.*
from "product" p
where exists (select pf.ProductId
              from product_filter pf 
              where pf.ProductId = p.ProductId and
                    pf.filterValueId = 4
             ) and
      exists (select pf.ProductId
              from product_filter pf 
              where pf.ProductId = p.ProductId and
                    pf.filterValueId = 8
             );
```

Comment: So the query returns by sequelize is not correct? I just tried your second proposition and it works. How faster than the first one is it if I have 5 differents `filterValueId`? Actually I need the filter_value table because it contains all the possible filterId values. The product_filter table is just pointing at them.

Comment: The first one works also. Wich one should I use for performance matter considering there could be lot of `filterValueId`. Thank you for your answer. It helps me a lot.

Comment: @Tom . . . I would go for the first version, because it is easier to code and should scale well.  However, you might want to try out and see which works better in your case.

Answer (score 0):

```
"filter_value"."filterValueId" = '4' AND "filter_value"."filterValueId" = '8
```

`filterValueId`  cannot be 4 and 8 at the same time.

Maybe you want

```
"filter_value"."filterValueId" = '4' OR "filter_value"."filterValueId" = '8
```

Comment: Actually, it is possible. But probably not the way I did. Gordon Linoff proposed something working.

Comment: @Tom What is actually possible? That filterValueId  of a row is 4 and 8 at the same time? No, that is not possible.